# Dynamically generated database through PHP not showing in the Cpanel

Tags: php

In my project I am creating database from PHP script. When I login in Cpanel I cannot see that particular Database which is created from PHP script. 
As discussed with the host technical guide they say :
"If the database create through the command line not as the cpanel user, the databases will not be owned by the cpanel account. You can map the database to the cpanel account after it is created. You will need to look into your code and update to have the cpanel user create the database, or run the map script from the server after the creation to map the db to the cpanel account."

Please suggest how can I see the Databases in Cpanel which are created from the PHP Script.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems the tech guide has given you plenty of information and tips to start with. Have you tried any?

Comment: I have provide the information in quoted text that tech guide has provided. I am not understanding what i have to do. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Well obviously..., but where are you stuck? Have you tried any of the given tips?

Comment: How can I map the Database through PHP script from different user.